# How can I run a Python script at an exact time in Windows 10?

Tags: python

I am using Windows 10. I have a Python script that I would like to run at a scheduled time every day without having to open the Python IDE and clicking run. Does anyone know how I can do this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the windows task scheduler ?

Comment: I'd never heard of it up until now. Thanks. Just out of curiosity. Assuming the laptop/PC is completely turned off. I'm assuming windows task scheduler would not be able to work. Is there a cloud equivalent? whereby it could pick the python file from one drive for example and run it from there?. The script itself gets data online, downloads it, transforms the data and maybe send an email. Just wondering.

Comment: you could get a server that runs 24/7 and run the script from there after scheduling it (see cron jobs if you use a linux machine) ; or maybe you can manage something on your computer. If it is shutdown, normal task scheduling won't work, you need to manage you UEFI settings to make sure your machine wakes up on time and then you can use the task scheduler to run a task every time it boots up.  This article [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/schedule-windows10-shut-down-start-up/) explains some of the steps, but I've never done it myself so maybe more research has to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I'll be sure to check it out. Regarding getting a server that runs 24/7, that's possible on Windows right?. I've not read it all yet but just having a glance at the article you shared the person is using task scheduler to shut down and start his PC. Unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: I think it's possible to get a server that runs windows if you find the correct host (not sure how windows server works compared to a standard windows instance), or you can use a windows container or virtual machine for that purpose. I imagine that can be a bit difficult to setup. The article linked above explains how one can modify the UEFI settings to boot up the computer at a specific time every day, however it is not using a server to do so, the author is just using his local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at scheduled tasks (like cron jobs on Linux)

E.g. here: https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows/Scheduled_tasks_and_cron_jobs_on_Windows/